# Roots of the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, alternative-proof

I'm looking for a proof (using basic tools : definition of the characteristic polynomial and its basic properties) of the following fact : 
The roots of the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix (with real coefficients) are reals.

Thank you.

Comment: It's quite simple proving that all eigenvalues are real with the definition of eigenvalue. I've never seen a proof using the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: That's why I was surprised when I saw this exercise...

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
Roots are the eigenvalues. So, we consider the eigenvalues equation of $M = M\+$. If an eigenvalue is zero, it is proved. So, we consider non null eigenvalues $\braces{\lambda}$:
$$
\left.%
\begin{array}{rcl}
M{\bf v} & = & \lambda{\bf v}\,,\
\mbox{with}\ {\bf v}\ \mbox{non null}
\\
{\bf v}\+\lambda^{*} & = & {\bf v}\+M\+
\end{array}\right\rbrace
\quad\imp\quad
0 = \pars{\lambda - \lambda^{*}}{\bf v}\+ M{\bf v}
=
\pars{\lambda - \lambda^{*}}\lambda\,{\bf v}\+{\bf v}
$$
Then, $\quad\color{#0000ff}{\large \lambda^{*} = \lambda}$.

Comment: Thank you but when I saw this exercise I was thinking of a solution using the characteristic polynomial.